# hot restart failed to complete: _flutter.runInView: (-32000) Could not run configuration in engine

Tags: flutter, dart

While trying to Hot restart app is getting crash . below is flutter doctor -v

flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2428], locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 3.13.8 on channel stable at C:\dev\flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 6c4930c4ac (6 days ago), 2023-10-18 10:57:55 -0500
• Engine revision 767d8c75e8
• Dart version 3.1.4
• DevTools version 2.25.0

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0-rc2)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\0001a\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0-rc2
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.4)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.4.33213.308
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)`your text`
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[√] VS Code (version 1.83.1)
• VS Code at C:\Users\0001a\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.74.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
• sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)
• Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2428]
• Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 118.0.5993.89
• Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 118.0.2088.61

[√] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

**And this is the log of flutter attach
**

```
flutter attach
Waiting for a connection from Flutter on sdk gphone64 x86 64...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64...                     11.8s

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload. 
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

A Dart VM Service on sdk gphone64 x86 64 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:61624/JsCcId6gYNQ=/
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on sdk gphone64 x86 64 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:61624/JsCcId6gYNQ=/

Performing hot restart...                                               
Restarted application in 1,538ms.
Application finished.
hot restart failed to complete: _flutter.runInView: (-32000) Could not run configuration in engine.
#0      new _OutstandingRequest (package:vm_service/src/vm_service.dart:1928:45)
#1      VmService._call (package:vm_service/src/vm_service.dart:2493:21)
#2      VmService.callServiceExtension (package:vm_service/src/vm_service.dart:2464:14)
#3      VmService.callMethod (package:vm_service/src/vm_service.dart:2446:12)
#4      FlutterVmService.callMethodWrapper (package:flutter_tools/src/vmservice.dart:579:28)
#5      FlutterVmService.runInView (package:flutter_tools/src/vmservice.dart:658:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:525:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      HotRunner._launchInView (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:552:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:525:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      HotRunner._launchFromDevFS (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:572:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     HotRunner._restartFromSources (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:673:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     HotRunner._fullRestartHelper (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:794:16)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     HotRunner.restart (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:734:38)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     TerminalHandler._commonTerminalInputHandler (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:1791:40)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     TerminalHandler.processTerminalInput (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:1831:7)
<asynchronous suspension>


Waiting for a new connection from Flutter on sdk gphone64 x86 64...
Error connecting to the service protocol: Exception: connection to device ended too early
```

Here is my Main Function :

```
const bool useEmulator = false;
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  try {
    await Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) => print(value));
    if (useEmulator == true) {
      await _connectToFirebaseEmulator();
      await FirebaseAppCheck.instance
          .activate(androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug);
    }



    runApp(const MyApp());
  } catch (error) {
    print('setup has failed\n $error');
  }
}
```

**I have already tried with flutter clean and flutter upgrade but no luck **

Comment: What does `MyApp()` look like?